# ORACLE - spring data jpa with null query parameter

Tags: spring, jpa

I have 3 queries:

1.

```
@Query(value = "select * from ACCOUNT_TRANSACTION at where 
at.TRANS_DATETIME >= coalesce(:#{#fromDate}, at.TRANS_DATETIME)", 
nativeQuery = true)
```

2.

```
@Query(value = "select * from ACCOUNT_TRANSACTION at where 
(:#{#fromDate} is null or at.TRANS_DATETIME >= :#{#fromDate}) ", 
nativeQuery = true)
```

3.

```
@Query(value = "select at from AccountTransaction at where 
:#{#fromDate} is null or at.transDatetime >= :#{#fromDate} ")
```

Query 1,2 not working with an error message:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got BINARY.

Query 3 working!

Column:

```
@XmlElement(name = "transDatetime")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
private Date transDatetime;
@Basic
@Column(name = "TRANS_DATETIME")
public Date getTransDatetime() {
    return transDatetime;
}

public void setTransDatetime(Date transDatetime) {
    this.transDatetime = transDatetime;
}
```

Can you show me where I'm wrong in 1,2. Thanks!

Updated:

4.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_TRANSACTION at WHERE at.TRANS_DATETIME >= (CASE  WHEN :#{#fromDate} is null then at.TRANS_DATETIME ELSE :#{#fromDate} END )", nativeQuery = true)
```

I tried by case when query but does not work.
Seem native query fail at all.

---

## Resolved:

http://betterlogic.com/roger/2012/03/java-sql-sqlsyntaxerrorexception-ora-00932-inconsistent-datatypes-expected-number-got-binary/

Comment: Could you check or clarify which are the columns being selected for query number 3? Is this a typo?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: I got success with mysql database, but got fail with Oracle.

Comment: What is the output of `:#{#fromDate}`? Please mae sure that it is of date type.

Comment: Here you are:
Page<AccountTransaction> findAllBy(Pageable pageable, @Param("fromDate") Date fromDate);

Comment: When I assign null value then error, but with date value then success

Comment: Seems with native query I cannot get success. I will change to case when query. Thank you for your helping.

Comment: I changed to case when query but got fail. Please help me!

Comment: Please move your solution to its own answer, including the code, thank you.